# Appending <option> only appending to last element in list

Tags: javascript, html

I use `querySelectorAll` to select 2 `select` elements. I then append a newly created `<option>` element to the two `<select>` elements.

However, for some reason only the last element has the option appended, the first one is ignored for some reason.

Here is my code:

```
displayLoading() {
    let dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('[data-search-select]');
    let loadingOption = document.createElement('option');
    loadingOption.innerHTML = 'Loading...';

    for(let i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        dropdowns[i].disabled = true;
        dropdowns[i].innerHTML = '';
        dropdowns[i].appendChild(loadingOption);
    }
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="formgroup">
    <label class="dropdown-search__label">Choose a make:</label>
    <select name="dropdown-search__select--make" id="dropdown-search__select--make" data-search-select="make">
    </select>
</div>

<div class="formgroup last">
    <label class="dropdown-search__label">Choose a model:</label>
    <select name="dropdown-search__select--model" id="dropdown-search__select--model" data-search-select="model">
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Node.appendChild()` is not creating  a copy.It is moving the existing node .so in your for loop it add option to the first select then moves it to the second and so on .So instead of that create two option elements and append to each  select :

```js
displayLoading();

function displayLoading() {
    let dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('[data-search-select]'); 
    for(let i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      
        let loadingOption = document.createElement('option');
        loadingOption.innerHTML = 'Loading...';
      
        dropdowns[i].disabled = true;
        dropdowns[i].innerHTML = '';
        dropdowns[i].appendChild(loadingOption);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="formgroup">
    <label class="dropdown-search__label">Choose a make:</label>
    <select name="dropdown-search__select--make" id="dropdown-search__select--make" data-search-select="make">
    </select>
</div>

<div class="formgroup last">
    <label class="dropdown-search__label">Choose a model:</label>
    <select name="dropdown-search__select--model" id="dropdown-search__select--model" data-search-select="model">
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You are creating one `option` element and trying to add it to two different selects. The second time you try to append the element, you grab the only option you have, remove from the current select and place into the new one. You should create **two** option elements, maybe moving that line into the for loop

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Can I not use the same element twice? Like as reference or something?

Comment: @MartynBall Nope, each dom element is its own thing